# The ntext data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which is joined by multiple queries and multiple tables if i run this query I am getting an error like this :

> 1. The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.
> 2. The ntext data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.

The table structure is:

[image: Design of tables and datatype]

and the query is this :

```
SELECT p.Proj_uid, p.proj_name,p.Agency,p.District,p.Division,p.ProjStatus,Civilbill80.billcount as Civilbill80, 
Civilbill20.billcount as Civilbill20 ,Civilbillpay.billcount as FinalCivilBill,CivilWorkslip.billcount as CivilWorkslip,
 Electribill80.billcount as Electricbill80, Electribill20.billcount as Electricbill20, Electribillpay.billcount as FinalElectriBill,
 ElectriWorkslip.billcount as ElectriWorkslip  FROM tempproj p
  LEFT JOIN (
             SELECT distinct(Proj_name),BillType,COUNT(1) as billcount  FROM payment_80   where BillType='CIVIL'
              GROUP BY Proj_name, BillType ) Civilbill80 ON Civilbill80.Proj_name = p.proj_name 
 LEFT JOIN (
             SELECT distinct(Proj_name),billtype,COUNT(1) as billcount FROM Payment_20    where billtype='CIVIL'
              GROUP BY Proj_name, billtype ) Civilbill20 ON Civilbill20.Proj_name = p.proj_name 
 LEFT JOIN (
             SELECT distinct(Proj_name),BillType, COUNT(1) as billcount  FROM payment_80  where BillType='Electric'
              GROUP BY Proj_name, BillType  ) Electribill80 ON Electribill80.Proj_name = p.proj_name 
 LEFT JOIN (
             SELECT distinct(Proj_name),billtype, COUNT(1) as billcount  FROM Payment_20  where billtype='Electric'
              GROUP BY Proj_name, billtype ) Electribill20 ON Electribill20.Proj_name = p.proj_name 
 LEFT JOIN (
             SELECT distinct(Proj_name),billtype, COUNT(1) as billcount   FROM Payment  where billtype='CIVIL'
              GROUP BY Proj_name, billtype ) Civilbillpay ON Civilbillpay.Proj_name = p.proj_name 
 LEFT JOIN (
             SELECT distinct(Proj_name),billtype, COUNT(1) as billcount  FROM Payment  where billtype='CIVIL'
              GROUP BY Proj_name, billtype  ) Electribillpay ON Electribillpay.Proj_name = p.proj_name
LEFT JOIN (
             SELECT distinct(proj_uid),item_type, COUNT(1) as billcount  FROM WorkSlipAmounts where item_type='WorkSlip'
              GROUP BY proj_uid, item_type ) CivilWorkslip ON CivilWorkslip.proj_uid = p.proj_uid
 LEFT JOIN (
             SELECT distinct(proj_uid),item_type, COUNT(1) as billcount  FROM WorkSlipAmounts  where item_type='ElecWorkSlip'
              GROUP BY proj_uid, item_type) ElectriWorkslip ON ElectriWorkslip.proj_uid = p.proj_uid
```

[image]

Please help me out .
Thank you so much

Answer (score 19):

SQL Server's [ntext, text, and image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) datatypes are obsolete:

> **ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version
>   of Microsoft SQL Server.** Avoid using these data types in new
>   development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use
>   them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.

Possible solution:

1. Identify columns that use these datatypes

2a. (Correct way) Alter table and change datatypes to `NVARCHAR/VARBINARY`

2b. (Workaround) Or in `SELECT DISTINCT` use: `CAST(col_name AS NVARCHAR(MAX))`,
 the same for join condition like `CAST(p.proj_name AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) = CAST(Civilbill20.proj_name AS NVARCHAR(MAX))`

Comment: Ya i tried this but i have joined multiple tables so i have prefixed the table name as p.proj_name so it is showing me the error in p. if i remove p. and write a simple and single query im getting the answer but i need to join the tables by matching eg: p.proj_name =Civilbill20.proj_name .

Comment: @habeeb `CAST(p.proj_name AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) = CAST(Civilbill20.proj_name AS NVARCHAR(MAX))`

Comment: do i need to convert all the rows in the table or only the matching row

Comment: You need to cast all occurences. Alter tables if possible it will be much easier.

Comment: can u please write the query for at least 3 tables , Please

Comment: @habeeb Without http://sqlfiddle.com not. The case is very simple. **If you don't want to fix your schema use casting.** Start small. Comment all joins except one, add casting and check result. Then add casting to all joins.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the bad design.

In your linked table design, all ntext fields are - NAMES. Seriously? Project name up to 4gb?

Assign a sensible limitation to the length, then change that to be a NVARCHAR(x) (with being the length).

Once you did this, fix the bad programming. A project name has to be unique. If you formulate your queries correctly, there is no need for a (very expensive - as in slow) distinct to start with.

At the end this runs down to 2 beginner mistakes:

- Bad table design, using large text data types to hold short pieces of information.
- Bad query design that has unneeded Distinct clauses.

In your case it even looks like all the distinct make no sense logically because the data already is distinct thanks to group by.

Comment: ya I will remove that distinct but i cannot change the design because it is a huge project and if i made changes then i have to solve the issues again and that will take lot of time ... now the project is working fine only thing which i need to introduce that query and i need to display the records

Comment: Well, tell you how it is: if I see a table design like that, I would change it. Not only the design - I would change the person making it and fire whoever thought using NTEXT for project names makes sense. Explanation: Incompetence. This is the core problem. You can not even put a unique index on them there (and you need them for guaranteeing unique naming). The design is BROKEN.

Comment: thank you so much @TomTom ... this is done by my seniors ... now it is headache for me

Comment: Point them here. The use of BLOB / Large data fields should be a last resort - definitely NOT for short elements. They cut out a lot of functionality and are intrinsically slower. Someone up there is doing a job he is not qualified for.